# c++ How to initialize char in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class MyClass
    {
        private :
        char str[848];

        public :

        MyClass()
        {

        }

        MyClass(char a[])  
        {
            str[848] = a[848];
        }

        MyClass operator () (char a[])
        {
            str[848] = a[848];
        }

        void myFunction(MyClass m)
        {

        }

        void display()
        {
            cout << str[848];
        }
    };

    int main()
    {   
        MyClass m1;  //MyClass has just one data member i.e. character array named str of size X
                                //where X is a constant integer and have value equal to your last 3 digit of arid number
        MyClass m2("COVID-19") , m3("Mid2020");
        m2.display(); //will display COVID-19
        cout<<endl;
        m2.myFunction(m3);
        m2.display(); //now it will display Mid2020
        cout<<endl;
        m3.display(); //now it will display COVID-19
      //if your array size is even then you will add myEvenFn() in class with empty body else add myOddFn()
      return 0;    

    }
```

I cannot use `string` because I'm told not to, therefore, I need to know how I can make it such that it displays the desired output

Comment: The line `str[848] = a[848];` does not do what you probably meant.

Comment: Yea, that's why I want to know what to do here

Comment: You need to clarify what the task is. Even if you have to avoid using `std::string` you may store the string either as a `char*` or `char[]`, and each option has it's own pros and cons. To say nothing about storing it as a `std::unique_ptr<char>`, `std::shared_ptr<char>` or `std::array<char, 848>`...

Comment: Why 848? Do you need precisely 847 characters in something? You probably want `std::string` in every case here. If you need to avoid `std::string` for whatever reason, allocate a buffer the size you actually need, not some seemingly random length.

Comment: It's assigned that we should use the length as our last 3 digits or roll number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to initialize `char` array in constructor?

1. Use a loop to copy element by element:

```
MyClass(char a[])  
{
    //make sure that sizeof(a) <= to sizeof(str);
    // you can not do sizeof(a) here, because it is
    // not an array, it has been decayed to a pointer

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); ++i) {
        str[i] = a[i];
    }
}
```

2. Use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>`

```
const int size = 848;
std::copy(a, a + size, str);
```

Prefer `std::copy` over `strcpy`, if you have to use `strcpy`, prefer `strncpy` instead. You can give size to it, so it can help prevent errors and buffer overflows.

```
MyClass(char a[])  
{
    strncpy(str, a, sizeof(str));
}
```

3. Use `std::array` from the library. It has various advantages, for e.g you can directly assign it like normal variables. Example:

```
std::array<char, 848> str = {/*some data*/};
std::array<char, 848> str1;
str1 = str;
```

Answer (score 2):

To copy a string you have to use [std::strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy), not `str[848] = a[848]`.

`str[848] = a[848]` copy only one element, but in your case it's a mistake, becasue your array has indexes [0, 847].

Try

```
class MyClass
{
    private :
    char str[848];

    public :

    MyClass()
    {

    }

    MyClass(char a[])  
    {
        std::strcpy(src, a);
    }

    MyClass operator () (char a[])
    {
        std::strcpy(src, a);
    }

    void myFunction(MyClass m)
    {

    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << str;
    }
};
```